# Sanitizing CSV data prior to importing to access database

Tags: csv, ms-access

Is there a nice formula to properly sanitize CSV data in-order to properly import it to the Access database?

Long story short I do have a rather boring monthly task of analyzing about 3600+ rows of data each month. Data is pulled straight from the server and I have no control of data formatting prior to receiving it. The only field that's giving me troubles is a mixed date/time field. Unfortunately data stored on the server includes milliseconds, and when retrieved it comes out in a following format (24h):

```
M/D/YYYY HH:MM:SS:MSMSMS
```

This causes an Access error when importing to Access database. Later on, data needs to be presented in the report in the following format (24h):

```
DD MMM YYYY HHMM
```

From my understanding, the most optimal way is to convert string to the proper date/time field as early as possible. I could in theory use Excel to sanitize the data via string manipulation but I prefer to minimize the use of two Office programs if possible. I'd like to just import it to Access, query as needed and print the report all in one shot using VBA. I'm also quite sure that there must be a better way to do it than string manipulation.

Also please let me know if I'm going completely ass backwards about it. I'm just learning Access.

Thank you for your interest and I appreciate any help and inputs.

Comment: No, there is no 'nice formula' to fix. However, latest version of Access has a new data type - date/time extended - that should be able to handle. What version of Access are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice expression to extract the date/time only:

```vb
TextDateTime = "6/7/2023 13:45:34:123456"

? Left(TextDateTime, InStrRev(TextDateTime, ":") - 1)
6/7/2023 13:45:34
```

However, as your final format should be `DD MMM YYYY HHMM`, you probably don't use the US locale with the reversed date format, thus converting this string with `CDate` would often return the wrong month-date:

```vb
? Cdate("6/7/2023 13:45:34")
2023-07-06 13:45:34
```

So, apply a function to parse it correctly like my `CDateUS`:

```vb
? CdateUS("6/7/2023 13:45:34")
2023-06-07 13:45:34
```

```vb
' Converts a US formatted date/time string to a date value.
'
' Examples:
'   7/6/2016 7:00 PM    -> 2016-07-06 19:00:00
'   7/6 7:00 PM         -> 2018-07-06 19:00:00  ' Current year is 2018.
'   7/6/46 7:00 PM      -> 1946-07-06 19:00:00
'   8/9-1982 9:33       -> 1982-08-09 09:33:00
'   2/29 14:21:56       -> 2039-02-01 14:21:56  ' Month/year.
'   2/39 14:21:56       -> 1939-02-01 14:21:56  ' Month/year.
'   7/6/46 7            -> 1946-07-06 00:00:00  ' Cannot read time.
'   7:32                -> 1899-12-30 07:32:00  ' Time value only.
'   7:32 PM             -> 1899-12-30 19:32:00  ' Time value only.
'   7.32 PM             -> 1899-12-30 19:32:00  ' Time value only.
'   14:21:56            -> 1899-12-30 14:21:56  ' Time value only.
'
' 2018-03-31. Gustav Brock. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function CDateUs( _
    ByVal Expression As String) _
    As Date
    
    Const PartSeparator As String = " "
    Const DateSeparator As String = "/"
    Const DashSeparator As String = "-"
    Const MaxPartCount  As Integer = 2

    Dim Parts           As Variant
    Dim DateParts       As Variant
    
    Dim DatePart        As Date
    Dim TimePart        As Date
    Dim Result          As Date
    
    ' Split expression into maximum two parts.
    Parts = Split(Expression, PartSeparator, MaxPartCount)
    
    
    If IsDate(Parts(0)) Then
        ' A date or time part is found.
        ' Replace dashes with slashes.
        Parts(0) = Replace(Parts(0), DashSeparator, DateSeparator)
        If InStr(1, Parts(0), DateSeparator) > 1 Then
            ' A date part is found.
            DateParts = Split(Parts(0), DateSeparator)
            If UBound(DateParts) = 2 Then
                ' The date includes year.
                DatePart = DateSerial(DateParts(2), DateParts(0), DateParts(1))
            Else
                If IsDate(CStr(Year(Date)) & DateSeparator & Join(DateParts, DateSeparator)) Then
                    ' Use current year.
                    DatePart = DateSerial(Year(Date), DateParts(0), DateParts(1))
                Else
                    ' Expression contains month/year.
                    DatePart = CDate(Join(DateParts, DateSeparator))
                End If
            End If
            If UBound(Parts) = 1 Then
                If IsDate(Parts(1)) Then
                    ' A time part is found.
                    TimePart = CDate(Parts(1))
                End If
            End If
        Else
            ' A time part it must be.
            ' Concatenate an AM/PM part if present.
            TimePart = CDate(Join(Parts, PartSeparator))
        End If
    End If
    
    Result = DatePart + TimePart
        
    CDateUs = Result

End Function
```

Full code and documentation at **GitHub**: [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date).